# "Error getting endorser client for query" when trying cli interaction with hyperledger fabric example, despite successful installation

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm currently trying to get the [example for hyperledger fabric](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/test_network.html) working. I get as far as starting the chaincode successfully using the deployCC script, and get the expected printout of all the cars after running the script. However, when I get to the next step of manually querying the network, I run into issue. I've run the exports for org1 as specified, and verified that the paths match and the tls cert and mspconfig exist in those locations. However, when I try to run the query command:

```
peer chaincode query -C mychannel -n fabcar -c '{"Args":["queryAllCars"]}'
```

I get the following error printout:

```
Error: error getting endorser client for query: endorser client failed to connect to 0.0.0.0:7051: failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded
```

I would expect to get the same printout as at the end of the deployCC script, and I can't figure out why that isn't happening. Any help in diagnosing this is appreciated!

If it matters, I'm running this in a VM with Ubuntu 20.04. All the prerequisites are fresh installations of the latest versions from the last couple of days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Liam, if you are able to see all the cars at the end of deployCC, then it might be an environment variables issue.  Remember that you have to execute the `peer chaincode query -C mychannel -n fabcar -c '{"Args":["queryAllCars"]}'` command in the same terminal where you ran deployCC because the environment variables are all set in that window.

We can do a couple of things to confirm:

1. Paste the output from DeployCC at the end, right after (and including)

   ```
   Querying chaincode on peer0.org1... 
   Using organization
   ```
2. Print the following environment variables from the terminal window where you are executing deployCC and from the terminal window where you are executing the `peer chaincode query -C mychannel -n fabcar -c '{"Args":["queryAllCars"]}'` command

> ```
> CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID, 
> CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE,
> CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH, 
> CORE_PEER_ADDRESS.
> ```

See if they match?

Comment: Thansk for the reply! Turns out, I had misspelled CORE_PEER_ADDRESS as CORE_PEER_ADRESS. Silly mistake that I should have caught!